# Consulta mysql que muestre coincidencias y luego el resto de filas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Tengo una base de datos MySql en la que guardo actividades con la siguiente estructura.

`id (int) | nombre(varchar) | descripcion(text) | mes(tinyint)`

Lo que estoy intentado conseguir es mostrar en php un listado de las mismas a partir del mes en curso.

Hasta ahora lo resolví haciendo 2 consultas separadas y luego repitiendo los resultados de forma consecutiva en html...

```
$mesactual = date("m")-1;
```

.php

```
$stm = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades WHERE mes >= $mesactual ORDER BY mes");
$stm -> execute();
$resultado = $stm -> fetchAll();

$stm = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades WHERE mes < $mesactual ORDER BY mes");
$stm -> execute();
$resultado2 = $stm -> fetchAll();
```

.html

```
foreach ($resultado as $item){
...
}
foreach ($resultado2 as $item){
...
}
```

Hay alguna forma de unificar en una sola consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner un `CASE` en el `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *   FROM actividades 
ORDER BY 
CASE mes
    WHEN mes LIKE $mesactual THEN 1
END 
desc ;
```

O Hacer una `UNION ALL` y excluir los primeros

```
SELECT * FROM actividades 
WHERE mes >= $mesactual 
UNON ALL 
SELECT * FROM actividades 
WHERE mes <> $mesactual
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz un `CASE` en la Consulta `SQL`

```
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN mes >= $mesactual THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ordenamiento FROM actividades ORDER BY ordenamiento DESC, mes ASC
```

el case dentro del select me devolvera 1 ó 0 por lo cual lo uso en el ordenamiento dandole prioridad al ordenamiento de mayor a menor con el orden de los meses

Comment: Aunque esto funcionaría, sería interesante si explicaras a OP por qué o cómo funciona.